# Will the PCB from the project found online work the same as the one from the video?

Tags: pcb, diodes, diagram

I've to construct 8x8x8 LED cube. I'm not interested in electronics but I have to make this project.

I've found [this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mN5JWQUfrxY&t=683s)

I don't want to solder paths myself so I'd like to go for the PCB but the project does not include the Gerber file.

I searched for a similar one and [found this.](https://oshwlab.com/alex.kost/led_qub_8x8x8-20a70d70e61f4f599c07546a7e8ece52)

The circuit diagram looks almost identical in both projects except for the Arduino part.

Video diagram:

[image: video diagram]

OSHWLab diagram:

[image: oshwlab diagram]

If I order this:

[image: pcb]

Will it look and work like this:

[image: cube]

Comment: If you build the same thing, it will work the same. The second diagram is drawn differently (parts moved around on the diagram, but connected the same) and also has two extra LEDs.

Comment: So, assuming that I don't mess up the soldering of the LED grid, if I order the PCB from OSHWLab project it will work? Also, this project has 11 different photos of the PCB. Which one should I choose?

Comment: @Scouteeer You're trying to pull together pieces from several different, poorly documented projects. You say you're not interested in electronics. I believe you will find this frustrating, and I recommend instead a more complete "LED Cube DIY kit" which you can find from $15 to $50 online.

Comment: @MarkLeavitt I'd do this, but my professor wants me to send the project to him (in easyeda). DIY kits usually do not contain any kind of project documentation or there's the name of the company that sells this KIT on PCB

Comment: If you build the same thing the same way, it will work the same. If you build something different, it will work different. Maybe it's not so useful to build something without really understanding how it works, unless the point of the project is soldering practice.

Comment: From my perspective, the point of this project is to pretend that I did it myself. So I need a project in easyeda (it's a requirement) and a working led cube. Soldering LEDs is not a problem for me. Just want to get the mark and forget about electronics forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ordered the OSHWLab project PCB and did the same thing as on the video. It works.

Answer (score 0):

1. In both cases you will have to solder the cube from wires and LEDs. Neither project has a PCB to put all of the LEDs on.
2. The OSHWLab project doesn't include the software or any description - using it will be difficult.
3. You've cut off all the interesting pieces from the diagrams you included.  The bits you've included are very similar, but the important part is how the serial communication with the IC on the LED PCB functions.

Comment: 1. soldering LEDs is something I cannot skip unfortunately
2. I wanted to use the software from the video. 
3. I don't exactly understand what do you mean by "how the serial communication with the IC on the LED PCB functions". But from what I see, both diagrams use the same components and they're connected to the same pins